# Call function for paired arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is simple script to generate greeting messages:

```
def greeting(event, person):
    print("Happy " + event + ", dear " + person + ".")

event = "Birthday"
person = "Emily"
greeting(event, person) # Happy Birtday, dear Emily.

event = "New Year"
person = "Mark"
greeting(event, person) # Happy New Year, dear Mark.
```

Is there way to get the same result, but call the `greeting` function only once?

Comment: Do you mean you want a loop in `greeting` that prints that line for each set of inputs?

Comment: Yes, I think this is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this in a loop to handle a list of names and events.  I'd recommend keeping the inner function the same, and firing a sequence of data at it from outside.  Depending on your application, mileage may vary.

```
def greeting(event, person):
    print("Happy " + event + ", dear " + person + ".")

event_list = [("Birthday", "Emily"),
              ("New Year", "Mark")]
for event, person in event_list:
    greeting(event, person)
```

Comment: I'm new in Python, could you elaborate why I get this error: `NameError: name 'greeting' is not defined`?

Comment: Did you include the function definition when you ran the code?

Comment: Currently I'm trying to understand where it should be)

Comment: Usually, at the top of the current block of code.  You have to define the function before you can call it.  I edited my answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to the function to loop over the inputs, this should work:

```
def greeting(messages):
    for event, person in messages:
        print("Happy " + event + ", dear " + person + ".")

greeting([('Birthday', 'Emily'), ('New Year', 'Mark')])
```

Comment: Mark is missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify greeting:

```
def greeting(info_pairs):
    for event, person in info_pairs:
         print("Happy " + event + ", dear " + person + ".")

greeting([("Birthday", "Emily"), ("New Year", "Mark")])
```

Comment: For the sake of honesty, I should note that answers from FamousJameous and sgrg are identical, except argument name.

Comment: @johnc.j.Yes, looks like I was a minute late hitting the "Submit" button!

Comment: No problems. It was posted simultaneously, and I leaved my comment just for another readers, to save their time when they would read all the answers and compare them.

Answer (score 1):

Either of the options mentioned by other users will work.  It depends on whether you want to put the loop in the function or outside of it:

```
def greeting(event, person):
    print("Happy " + event + ", dear " + person + ".")

for event, person in [("Birthday", "Emily"),
              ("New Year", "Mark")]:
    greeting(event, person)
```